# How to get rid of "No data available in table" message on the top row of the table data?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables

I have a React app. where am fetching earthquake data using usgs api, am using jQuery Datatables, but when am displaying the data in the table, the first row displays "No data available in table" message. And the rows below it are showing correct data.

How can i remove this line from table?

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02')
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({
                posts : response.data.features
            },()=>console.log(this.state.posts.features))
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
            this.setState({
                error : 'Error retrieving data'
            })
        })
}

render(){
    const{posts,error} = this.state
    return(
        <div>
        <table id="earthquakes">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Magnitude</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            {posts.length ?
            // posts.map(post=><div key={post.id}>{post.properties.place}</div>):
            posts.map(post=><QuakeShow key={post.id} post={post} ></QuakeShow>):
            null}

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class QuakeShow extends Component {
    render(){
        const {post} = this.props
        return(
            <tr>
                <td><img url="C:\Users\acer\Documents\ReactWorkspace\earthquake\resources\earthquake.png"/></td>
                <td>{post.properties.mag}</td>
                <td><a href={post.properties.url}>{post.properties.place}</a></td>
            </tr>    
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but I would avoid anything that uses jQuery within a React app. Try react-tables instead maybe

Comment: I would have built the tables from scartch. simple html and css..no quantum mechanics.

Comment: Add redux and time travel debugging (redux devtools) always helps me with these kind of 'missing data' bugs

Comment: thanks @EvaCohen but am a beginner and i don't know about redux yet

Comment: @DarrenSweeney okay i'll try that

Comment: Please console.log posts to help us debug.

Comment: try to console log the data in the first line of render method. check if all data available to the render method

Comment: @CraigGehring as u guys said i did console log, but nothing gets printed for that row, [link](https://ibb.co/sFgpyDm)

Comment: @EvaCohen check the link

Comment: Where in your code is the string ‘No data available in  table’? Please show us that.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery library doesn’t know that there is data in the table. It does not play nicely with React. You should either be using React or this library. If you remove the jquery your “No data” message there will disappear.